# CAN Open PDO mapping

Tags: canopen

I am new to CANopen protocol and could anyone help me with the difference between PDO2 and PDO3.I am receiving CAN data from the sensor and i could see the message type as TXPDO2, TXPDO3 etc. Is there any difference between the 2?